Java: Remove a collection of objects (for ex the info about a vehicle with ID xxx) from a list and return removed objects to new list
I want to remove a collection of objects from a List, the removed objects should be added to new list and returned. The expected return of removed object (car) when outprinted look like for ex:
[15NG22 Volvo Car] or [152235 Sherman Tank]
If no objects where removed from List, return null. In class Vehicle I have constructor:
public Vehicle(String vehicleID, String vehicleName, String vehicleType) {
   this.vehicleID = vehicleID; this.vehicleName = vehicleName;    
   this.vehicleType = vehicleType; 
}
// and Setters/Getters. 

In class VehicleShop:
Vehicle vehicle = new vehicle(vehicleID, vehicleName, vehicleType); 
List<String> listOfVehicles = new ArrayList<String>();

In the class VehicleShop I also have a function that going to handle removing a vehicle and it´s objects.
public List<String> deleteVehicle(String vehicleID) {
    
    List<String> deletedVehicleList = new ArrayList<String>(listOfVehicles);
    List<String> deletedVehicleDetailsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    Iterator<String> it = listOfVehicles.listIterator();
    
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        String next = (String) it.next();
        if(next.getVehicleID().equals(vehicleID)) {
            
            it.remove();
            
            System.out.println(next);
            deletedVehicleDetailsList.add(next);
            
            String deletedVehicleString = String.join(" ", deletedVehicleList);
            System.out.println(deletedCustomerList);
            
            Collections.addAll(deletedVehicleDetailsList, deletedVehicleString);
            System.out.println(deletedVehicleDetailsList);
            
            return deletedVehicleDetailsList;
        }
    }
    deletedVehicleDetailsList = null;
    
    return deletedVehicleDetailsList;

}
In the fuction addVehicle, when run the code it sucessfull add vehicles to the List vehicles (for ex [123, Volvo, Truck, 242, Cat, Bulldozer, 666, Baneblade, Tank...]. But when trying to delete a vehicle, I got error and it stops.
The error is in the if- statement in the While-iteration:
if(next.getVehicleID().equals(vehicleID)) and it is getVehicle()that get the error message: "The method getVehicle() is undefined for the type String".
I have tested other solutions, like
        if(listOfVehicles.contains(vehicleID)) {
        List<String> deletedVehicleList = listOfVehicles.stream()
                .filter(customer -> customer.getVehicleID().equals(vehicleID))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }else {
        deletedVehicleDetailsList = null;
    }

Still get same error with getVehicleID() . I have also tried Predicate and lambda, but still same result.
Thank you for any explanation and qlues what I have done/thought wrong.

Shouldn't you work with a List<Vehicle> instead of List<String> ?

I want to remove a collection of objects from a List There's some confusion here, as so far you've been attempting to remove only one object from the collection ...

These two lines should clearly show you that next is a string:
String next = (String) it.next();
if(next.getVehicleID().equals(vehicleID)) ....
Strings are not vehicles. They do not have functions like getVehicleID. They have functions like toUpper and toLower. A string is not a vehicle.  If you want to call getVehicleID, you should probably call it on a vehicle, not on a string, and your list might need to be a List for next to be of type vehicle.

  // not use a "String" list, a "Vehicle" list
List<Vehicle> listOfVehicles = new ArrayList<>();

  // return a "Vehicle" list
public List<Vehicle> deleteVehicle( String vehicleID ) {

      // creamos the list
    List<Vehicle> deletedVehicleList = new ArrayList<>();

      // a list containing the details of the deleted items
    List<String> deletedVehicleDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();

    Iterator<Vehicle> it = listOfVehicles.listIterator();
    while( it.hasNext() ) {

          // we cast “next” to “Vehicle” to be able to invoke “getVehicleID”
        Vehicle next = ( Vehicle ) it.next();
        if( next.getVehicleID().equals( vehicleID ) ) {

              // add to the out list
            deletedVehicleList.add( next );
            it.remove();
            System.out.println( next );
            deletedVehicleDetailsList.add( next.toString() );

              // it is not clear to me what the following lines make sense
            /*
            String deletedVehicleString = String.join( " ", deletedVehicleList );
            System.out.println( deletedCustomerList );
            Collections.addAll( deletedVehicleDetailsList, deletedVehicleString );
            System.out.println( deletedVehicleDetailsList );
            return deletedVehicleDetailsList;
             */
        }
    }
      // show info
    System.out.println( deletedVehicleDetailsList.toString() );
    return deletedVehicleList;
}

if you want to make it clearer:
public List<Vehicle> deleteVehicle( String vehicleID ) {
    
    List<Vehicle> deletedVehicleList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> deletedVehicleDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();    
    
    for( Vehicle veh : listOfVehicles ) {            
        if( veh.getVehicleID().equals( vehicleID )) {

              // show info
            System.out.println( veh.toString() );
              // add details list
            deletedVehicleDetailsList.add( veh.toString() );

              // add the object to the new list
            deletedVehicleList.add( veh );

             // delete the object from the previous list
            listOfVehicles.remove( veh );
            break;      
        }
    }
    System.out.println( deletedVehicleDetailsList.toString() );        
    return deletedVehicleList;    
} 


The remove method of List does not return the object; it returns boolean: true if the object was found and removed, false if not found. Also System.out.println( veh.toString() ); can be simplified to System.out.println( veh );

Your remove invokes not List#remove(T), but List.remove(int). Try c.remove(new Integer(0)) and see what happens. If you don't define toString() you'll invoke Object#toString from within println(), which is what you're seeing. Nevertheless, if you System.out.println( veh.toString() ); you'll get the exact same result.


As said before, your code invokes this remove method which does not return the object but a boolean. 2) Calling remove on a collection while you are iterating over it, is broken. That’s why the original code uses Iterator.remove. 3) This “clearer” code tries to return deletedVehicleDetailsList which has type List<String> despite the declared return type is List<Vehicle>.



While the OP’s original code already contains an obsolete type cast you maxed it out by adding another obsolete type cast, together with the incomprehensible comment “we set “Vehicle” to “Vehicle” to be able to invoke “getVehicleID””


Thanks for letting me know about the “we set ‘Vehicle’ to ‘Vehicle’, I was getting high??!!! haha.

You have linked to remove(int) which returns the object but you are passing a Vehicle object to the method, so you’re clearly invoking remove(Object) which returns a boolean.

@Holger, you are right, I have modified my answer, thank! you for your observation. :)

The type casts from Vehicle to Vehicle are still unnecessary. Further, there’s still the problem in the second variant that deletedVehicleDetailsList has type List<String> but the return type is List<Vehicle>, so you can’t return it.

@Holger, corrected!! thanks again!!!.

Now, the remaining question is, since you break out of the loop on the first match, in other words, only process at most one element, why maintaining those two lists? You could simply use if( veh.getVehicleID().equals( vehicleID )) { listOfVehicles.remove(veh); System.out.println(veh); System.out.println("[" + veh + "]"); return List.of(veh); }, to the same effect (and do System.out.println("[]"); return List.of(); after the loop for the case that there’s no match).

@holger, I try to keep what the OP believes, I'm not clear what he uses that list for, but since he didn't come back to the site, there's no one to ask....
